# How to set default time in DE date field time using SQL in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sqlserver, sql-studio

whenever a record is created how to set the time in the Date field time value to 8AM by default.

```
SELECT CustomerID,
CreatedDate,
DATEADD(Day, 1, CreatedDate) As NextDate 
from TestCustomers
```

[image]

instead of 12AM in NEXTDATE field how can I show 8AM as a default time value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(Hour, 8, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(Day, 1, [CreatedDate]) AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) As NextDate
```

This will basically force the field to 8am on the next day after CreatedDate, regardless of what time of the day is in CreatedDate.
What I'm doing here is adding a day to CreatedDate, forcing it back to just a date (so the time part is removed), then forcing it to a DateTime (so it will say it's midnight of the next day) and then adding another 8 hours to make it 8am.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, ab.CreatedDate), '09:00:00') as NextDate
```